# SQL Query Problem With Three Tables

Tags: asp.net, sql, left-join

I've got three tables, I want to select two columns from the first table and one from the last table to be displayed in a gridview for asp.net

So I have a table Sprint, Task and Blocked.

I want to display CurrentStatus from blocked table and to do this I need to use the Task table to join them together. I've attempted the query below but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me on this please, it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @Karl. Please explain "doesn't work".

Comment: First off, start with the tblBlocked table (i.e., FROM tblBlocked ...) rather than joining it, then just use inner joins for the other tables. (That's assuming you only want to see blocked records anyway.)

Comment: And also - your trying to do an INNER JOIN on a LEFT JOIN, which doesnt make sense. The INNER JOIN should be first, and the LJ off that, or they should both be LJ.

Comment: Its displaying the records that are only in the blocked table. I want it to display all the records from the sprint table but just have the currentstatus from blocked table beside them. The reason I thought I wanted a left join to get all the records from sprint

Comment: @RPM. Is that necessarily true? What if you want all records in tblSprint, but you only want records from tblBlocked if they correspond to a record in tblTask?

Comment: @MarkSQLDEV - I just want to select all the sprints and also select their blocked status

Comment: @Karl, OK, then I misunderstood. Then what's wrong with the original query?

Comment: @Karl, I'm guessing that you also want a LEFT JOIN on your last join too rather than an INNER JOIN.  That way, all the rows from tblSprint will show up.

Comment: @Mark Its displaying only the results from the blocked table. e.g. I have sprint 1 and sprint 2 but only sprint 1 is in the blocked table so its the only row returned. Instead of Sprint 1 and Sprint 2 with Sprint 1 having status 'blocked' (apologies if this isn't making sense my SQL ain't the greatest anymore! :/ )

Comment: @mark I tried that aswell but then it returned multiple results, cause it would include all of the tasks in the query so returns all of them. So Sprint 2 would appear twice because there was more than 1 task assigned to sprint 2

Comment: Can you use DISTINCT or a GROUP BY clause then?

Answer (score 1):

The way that you are doing it now, you are doing

- first a LEFT JOIN on Task (which keeps the Sprint entries without a Task) and
- then an INNER JOIN on Blocked (which removes the Sprint entries which don't have a Blocked entry).

Basically, you need to INNER JOIN Task and Blocked first, *then* RIGHT JOIN to Sprint (which gets all Sprints):

```
SELECT tblSprint.sprintID, tblSprint.projectID, tblBlocked.CurrentStatus 
FROM tblTask 
     INNER JOIN tblBlocked ON tblTask.taskID = tblBlocked.taskID
     RIGHT JOIN tblSprint ON tblTask.sprintID = tblSprint.sprintID
```

Alternatively, if that's easier to understand for you, you can write it like this: You LEFT JOIN Sprint to the *already combined* Task-Blocked data.

```
SELECT tblSprint.sprintID, tblSprint.projectID, tblBlocked.CurrentStatus 
FROM tblSprint LEFT JOIN (tblTask INNER JOIN tblBlocked 
                          ON tblTask.taskID = tblBlocked.taskID)
     ON tblSprint.sprintID = tblTask.sprintID
```

Comment: @Jordan: Yep. And since no fields from `tblTask` are selected, I hereby claim that our two solutions will always return the same result set.

Answer (score 0):

Well RPM is right. I just tested it, and you need two `LEFT JOIN`s.

Comment: Just read your comment, now your answer. Guess i was right, lol. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm just showing what RPM1984 and Jordan are saying here and I think they're correct:

Try this:

```
SELECT tblSprint.sprintID, tblSprint.projectID, tblBlocked.CurrentStatus  
FROM tblSprint  
     LEFT JOIN tblTask ON tblSprint.sprintID = tblTask.sprintID  
     LEFT JOIN tblBlocked ON  tblBlocked.taskID = tblTask.taskID
```